# Mutable vs. immutable binary tree traversal in C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree, immutability, mutability

I come from a Python and Haskell background, so when I had to write a function to count the number of movies in a binary tree, I did it like this:

```
int MovieTree::countMovieNodes(MovieNode* parent)
{
  if (parent)
    return countMovieNodes(parent->left) + countMovieNodes(parent->right) + 1;
  else
    return 0;
}

int MovieTree::countMovieNodes()
{ countMovieNodes(root); }
```

However, using the header file provided in class, I had to do it like this:

```
void MovieTree::countMovieNodes(MovieNode* parent, int* c)
{
  (*c)++;
  if (parent->left)
    countMovieNodes(parent->left, c);
  if (parent->right)
    countMovieNodes(parent->right, c);
}

int MovieTree::countMovieNodes()
{
  if (!root) return 0;
  int c=0; countMovieNodes(root, &c); return c;
}
```

I understand the advantages of the former over the latter very well; what are the advantages of the latter over the former? It has to do with stack memory usage, right?

Comment: I also have background in non-c++ so I'm curious to see what c++ is capable here. Good question.

Comment: There likely aren't any advantages (and note that you're invoking undefined behavior because `c` is never initialized to zero). The second version will actually take more stack space because it must push `c` to the stack.

Comment: I wonder why our prof had us do it that way then...huh.

Comment: @Cornstalks: Similar to what I was thinking. I was just afraid of writing anything as saying it has no advantage seemed wrong to me. The only advantage I can see is that the latter won't use any space on the heap.

Comment: @therainmaker Oh, right! How would one do it iteratively, though?

Comment: @therainmaker: the former also won't use any space on the heap. @ OP: you're professor probably had you do it that way because he's got old habits that die hard. School is good for learning CS theory, but the coding practices professors sometimes teach are crap.

Comment: @Cornstalks I can't imagine living one's life writing code like that XD that's why I love my Haskell

Comment: @Cornstalks: Suppose instead of an int, we had to return some other object, and instead of the `+1` in the return statement, it was `+object`. Then wouldn't space on the heap be allocated on every recursive call? If we instead did `(*c) + object`, I think the total heap usage across calls with be different. PS: If this comment is unclear, I'll ask a question on SO.

Comment: @cornstalks also, why would anyone ever have done it that way? ("old habits")

Comment: @therainmaker: I'm not sure what you mean by `+object`, because you can't add objects (unless `operator+` is overridden, in which case any answer is totally context sensitive). That usually wouldn't use the heap at all, unless `operator+` was overridden to do so. Perhaps post a question on SO and ping me if you want.

Comment: @RenéG: Well, the fact that the function takes a pointer instead of a reference suggests the professor comes from a C background (which doesn't have references), and so carries some habits from that. However, I'm not sure why the professor decided to pass `c` as a parameter. If I had to hazard a guess, I would guess that that is how s/he first learned to do it, and so is just habitually repeating it.

Comment: @therainmaker you are wrong.  I guess you mixed up other languages with C++.  Even it is returning an object, it is not necessary to involve heap space.  Objects in C++ is possible to live totally in stack.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any advantage in the second solution over the first solution. In fact, I think it is worse the first one. The first one is cleaner, with fewer lines of code that check against null pointers.

However, the title of your question is misleading. The second one is also recursive. It is not iterative.

Comment: Is the new title better?

Comment: @RenéG, I think it will better as "Compare two methods of traversing a binary tree to count the number of nodes"

Answer (score 1):

One thing that the latter way is doing bad in C++ style is, it is still passing pointer for the sake of effect of call by reference, for which in C++ we do have reference which makes the code cleaner and less error prone:

```
void MovieTree::countMovieNodes(MovieNode* parent, int& count)
{
  ++count;
  ....
}
```

Going back to the style of recursion, the style that is used by the latter case, can have better performance because of tail call optimization.

In short, TCO avoid call stack keep increasing for each level of recursive call.

In the former form, we need to keep stack for each level of recursive call so that we can have the results and do further calculation (in your case, calculating sum of count in two sub-tree).

For the latter case, compiler knows that it won't need to keep the stack for the second call of `countMovieNodes` (coz there is no further calculation) so that it can reuse current stack to do the recursive call (only for the second call if my understanding is correct).

However, in this specific case, the benefit may not be that huge because for latter case, first call of `countMovieNodes` cannot benefit from TCO.  It is still an advantage though.